# Cannot select SVG element by class unless using attribute selector

Tags: jquery, html, svg

For some reason, `$('#p-foo').siblings('.bar')` works, but `$('#g-foo').siblings('.bar')` does not. Can anyone point out to me why this is the case?

```
<div>
    <p id="p-foo"></p>
    <p class="bar"></p>
</div>

<svg>
    <g id="g-foo"></g>
    <g class="bar"></g>
</svg>
```

I wrote [a quick test script](http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/2LTf8/) to demonstrate the problem:

```js
var selector  = '.bar',
    attribute = '[class=bar]';

var check = function (foo, d) {
  console.log(d + ' matches ' + foo.siblings(d).length);
};

var p_foo = $('#p-foo');
console.log('DIV');
check(p_foo, selector);
check(p_foo, attribute);

var g_foo = $('#g-foo');
console.log('SVG');
check(g_foo, selector);
check(g_foo, attribute);
```

And the output is:

```
DIV
.bar matches 1
[class=bar] matches 1
SVG
.bar matches 0
[class=bar] matches 1
```

Comment: This is gold! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was an interesting problem, so I did a little source code research.

[`.siblings()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/traversing.js#L172)
calls
[`$.filter`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/traversing.js#L206), which delegates to Sizzle and eventually uses the filters [here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/c0d9badeb5dac649d0ba7824efaebbe4155369b5/sizzle.js#L947).

- If you use the `[class=bar]` selector, Sizzle uses the [`ATTR` filter](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/c0d9badeb5dac649d0ba7824efaebbe4155369b5/sizzle.js#L970), which simply retrieves the attribute and does an equality check against its value. This works for both `p` and `g`.
- If you use the `.bar` selector, Sizzle uses the [`CLASS` filter](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/c0d9badeb5dac649d0ba7824efaebbe4155369b5/sizzle.js#L960), which uses a regex against `elem.className`. In SVG elements, however, `className` is not a string, but an instance of `SVGAnimatedString` (which, to be perfectly honest, I've never fully wrapped my head around, but it seems to have both an `animValue` and a `baseValue`). The regex fails, and the element isn't matched.

I believe Sizzle has additional handling that might make this work if the entire document is
SVG or XML, but because this SVG is embedded in an HTML doc, that doesn't kick in.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I didn't know that bit about `SVGAnimatedString`.